# add a jQuery selector to the URL parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to add a jQuery selector to the URL parameter after an AJAX-request?
This is my perfectly working code:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "load_page.php",
    data : 'page=' + url,
    success : function(msg) {
        if (parseInt(msg) != 0)//if no errors
        {
            $content.fadeIn(200, function() {
            $('#content').html(msg);

            });
        }
    }
});
//load the returned html into pageContent
```

I know that via [.load()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp) (or [link](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) it is possible:

```
$("# content'").load("demo_test.txt #sub.content");
```

But is it possible via `$('#content').html(msg);`?

Additional info:
I am trying to only get the `<div id=”sub-content”>`

Comment: The `"/your/url #selector"` syntax only works in `.load()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, simply filter the data before appending it.

```
var $content = $("#content").empty();
$("<div>").html($.parseHTML(msg)).find("#sub").appendTo($content);
```